# Class organization to access abstract method from Android fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I'm not really sure what my problem statement is, as you can tell from the title. I have an abstract class A that extends Activity. Class A has an abstract method defined:

```
public abstract class A extends Activity {
    ActionBar.Tab devicesTab, otherTab;
    Fragment fragmentTab = new FragmentTab();

    protected abstract void connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect);
}
```

The class that implements connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect) extends Class A:

```
public class MainActivity extends A {

    @Override
    protected void connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, bActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, deviceToConnect);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Inside class A I have a Fragment which has its own class, class FragmentTab extends Fragment. This class holds the UI that allows the user to select the device to connect. I need to pass that device to class A or have access to connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect) so that the main activity can start with it. I have tried using "wrapper" methods but it always results in the method needing to be static, which doesn't let me use connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect) because it's an abstract protected method.

What can I do to solve this problem? Does it require another class? Or am I just missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to rethink your design.  Only another `Activity` should ever extend `Activity`. You cannot treat an activity like a POJO, and the framework must control its lifecycle.  Start by reading about `Interface`.  Using callbacks is probably what you want.

Comment: I should say, before using a Fragment the call to connectBluetooth(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect) was made from inside class A so there wasn't any problems, but I needed to separate out my UI using Fragments which resulted in finding the device to connect inside the Fragment class. Now I can't get that "device" back to class A.

Comment: @Simon is right. You need to re-think your design. I would just make a singleton `BluetoothUtil` class. Just add a `Context` object to your method parameters and use that object in place of `this`.

Comment: @sonictt1 This is super dangerous.  Pass a Context to a singleton.  Make that context an `Activity` reference.  Rotate your device and boom, instant memory leak.

Comment: @Simon Good point. I'd offer a correction on that possible solution, but OP found her solution, so I won't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to create an event callback to my activity from the Fragment. After Simon's comment, thank you Simon, I researched [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), interfaces, and callbacks. This solved my problem however I agree that the design could be reworked.

Inside the FragmentTab class I needed an interface:

```
OnDeviceSelectedListener mDeviceListener;

public interface OnDeviceSelectedListener
{
    public void onDeviceSelected(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect);
}
```

Also, needed to attach it to the activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try
    {
        mDeviceListener = (OnDeviceSelectedListener)activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement OnDeviceSelectedListner");
    }
}
```

After that the OnItemClickListener calls the OnDeviceSelected method which is implemented in class A.

```
...  mDeviceListener.onDeviceSelected(deviceToConnect);
```

Class A that implements the method must have the "implements" description:

```
public abstract class A extends Activity implements FragmentTab.OnDeviceSelectedListener
{   ...
}
```

And finally the implementation that resides in class A:

```
public void onDeviceSelected(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect)
{
    connectBluetooth(deviceToConnect);
}
```